# How can I find reference about a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ? (0x800A08FE)

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, error-handling, vba, office-interop

I've got an ASP.NET application that uses Microsoft Interop Services to dialog with Access.
Changing my IIS server, now I have an exception when calling:

```
oAccess.DoCmd.OutputTo (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport,
                       sReport,
                       acFormatPDF,
                       PDFFile,
                       moMissing,
                       moMissing,
                       moMissing);
```

The exception message is this:

> Microsoft Access can't save the output data to the file you've selected.

The exception code is this:

> 0x800A08FE

I can't find anything about this error code on the web, and I can't find any other suggestion on where to investigate from the catched error, because it returns nothing more than what I already wrote. This is the ASP.NET code that I used to catch error:

```
catch (Exception e) {
                     Log("Exception:" + e.ToString() + " Stacktrace: " + e.StackTrace + " Source: " + e.Source + " Message: " + e.Message);
                    }
```

I would really appreciate a suggestion on how to deepen error causes.

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: @JohnSaunders I was expecting a comment like this :-). I've got many complex reports in access, and I would like to exploit them in a web application without rewriting the VBA code and without redesign them. Do you occur a less horrible solution, or a possible path to follow?

Comment: Doesn't Access have a wizard to upgrade to SQL Server? Haven't Microsoft or someone else written a translator of some kind? Because calling Office Interop from a server application just doesn't work.

Comment: The database already is Sql Server. Reports are in an ADP Accdss project. I have a working solution on Windows Server 2003 with Access 2010. Now, upgrading to Windows Server 2008 with Access 2010 64bit I've got this problem. I'll give a look to some third party translator. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the hex error 0x800a08fe has this meaning:

- 0x800a stands for  COM Add-in error
- 0x08fe converted in integer (2302), is the Access error code.

Now I've got to understand why Access gives me this error, but only exporting in PDF format, not in RTF.

> Run-time error '2302':
>       Microsoft Access can't save the output data to the file you've selected.

I will ask a new specific question about this.